# Angular vs Angular Universal with NGRX Store

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx, angular-universal, ngrx-store

Angular vs Angular Universal with NGRX
Trying to understand how to work around @ngrx/store-devtools library for Angular Universal.
I've set up this project that is a ng seed project using Angular Universal.

It has a language switcher and I can't seem to understand how the store works.
Github project:
https://github.com/ng-seed/universal

In the code you can see there are reducers for when you switch language, but in the devtools the state shows empty, so can't understand how it pushed to the state or how the state gets managed.

Comment: did you just clone the project, or did you really setup store-devtools module? this seed project does not have this implemented (you need to import `StoreDevtoolsModule` in your `AppModule`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to setup the `@ngrx/store-devtools` module first, I just tried this on that seed project and it works ok.

1. Run `npm i @ngrx/store-devtools --save` to install the module.
2. Add `StoreDevtoolsModule.instrument()` to the end imports array in `CoreModule`.
3. Rebuild and serve (`npm run build:universal-dev && npm run serve`).

[image]